# Why does my if else statement refuses to read a certain row?

Tags: c#, if-statement, datagridview

I have a table below that contains the students' results in a DataGridView:-

```
ID  NAME    RESULT
1   Peter   PASS
1   Peter   SILVER
2   Sam     FAIL
2   Sam     SILVER
3   Simon   FAIL
4   Cliff   PASS
5   Jason   FAIL
5   Jason   FAIL
6   Leonard PASS
6   Leonard FAIL
```

I'm trying to produce a simple program that will filter out certain rows base on the Results upon a click of a button. What I have achieved right now is that I have able to filter out those who with PASS and/or SILVER as their Result and only display out FAIL.

The problem is right now whenever the button is clicked, it will removed the rows with a PASS and/or SILVER, except the 2nd Row: `1 Peter SILVER`. Leaving me with this table below as the end result:-

[image]

The only way to resolved this right now is to click the button again.

Below is the source code for the button:-

```
    private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (dtList.Rows.Count != 0)
       {
           try
           {
               foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dtList.Rows)
               {
                   //Column names in excel file
                   string colID = dr.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
                   string colName = dr.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
                   string colResult = dr.Cells["Result"].Value.ToString();


                   if (!colResult.Equals("FAIL", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                   {
                       dtList.Rows.Remove(dr);
                   }

               }
           }
           catch
           {

           }
        }

    }
```

Comment: That empty catch hurts you

Comment: This isn't an answer, but making the condition `Count > 0` makes more sense, and may matter latter down the line.

Comment: Also, will the code not fail when you try to remove rows from the collection you're iterating over?

Comment: I'm wonderning, if this works at all. Typically you can't remove elements from collections you are iterating.

Comment: @CallumLinington: I'm intrigued as to what situations you are thinking of where using `Count > 0` will be better than `Count != 0`? As for makes more sense that is just a matter of taste, I'd imagine...

Comment: As Tim says you should not be using this empty catch. This code may well be throwing errors that would give a clue to why it isn't working but you will never know...

Comment: @CallumLinington In my opinion the check for `Count` is not necessary at all (at least for that part of the code) because if there are no elements in the collection, no iteration is done (may be a minimal performance gain though)

Comment: @user3195396 try setting a breakpoint for the if and check what happens. and also add some sort of exception handling.

Comment: @Allan The code works perfectly if the 2nd row data is removed from the collection.

I have added 

`catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string errorCode = ex.Message.ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show(errorCode, "Error found");
                }`

No error thrown here.  

Breakpoints totally skip the 2nd row, and jumps straight to the 3rd Row

Comment: @derpirscher yeah completely agree with that. @Chris `!= 0` is a preference thing to some extent, but ` > 0` helps when you mean no negatives as well

Comment: When deleting items from a list you must iterate from last item to first. for(int index = dtList.Rows.Count - 1; index >= 0; index--)

Comment: You can modify a list you're iterating!! `dtList.Rows.Remove(dr);` Just store up all the elements you want to remove, and remove them after iteration!

Comment: @CallumLinington: Ah, yes. In other situations that may be relevant but I would hope in this case the count of rows is never negative! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are changing the list you are iterating over. This is never a great idea...

In this case you look at the first row (Peter/Pass) and remove it. You then look at the second row. But wait, we removed a row so the second row is in fact actually now the old third row - we have just skipped the original second row.

You don't notice this problem anywhere else because all other rows that want to be removed are followed by rows you want to keep.

The way to fix this is to either:

1. Create a new list with the items you want to keep and then bind
   that new list to whereever you are displaying
2. Create a list of items that you want to remove from the datatable
   while you are iterating the table. Then once you have a list of
   items you want to remove iterate over that list removing them from
   the datatable.
3. Iterate through the list with a for loop starting with the last
   index. This will mean that when you remove items you only effect
   those that come after which in this case you will have already
   processed.

The second is probably the easiest way to go in this situation. The first involves extra code and the third may not be obvious why you are doing that to somebody that comes after you.